# Linear regression with non-fixed regressors and some properties

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, linear-regression

I was talking to my teacher the other day about the OLS and linear regression model $Y = \beta X + \varepsilon$. If the regressors X are fixed numbers and I don't have the normal condition on the errors, then in order to have the asymptotic distribution of the OLS estimator (CLT) I need the condition (this also appears in Thomas Ferguson)
\begin{equation}
\frac{\max_i (X_i - \bar{X})^2}{n} \longrightarrow 0, n\rightarrow \infty.
\end{equation}

But then in an e-mail I was asking about the case where $X$ is random, and I get the response

> If the errors are not normal and $X$ has finite fourth moment, since $X$ is random we automatically have $$\frac{\max_i (X_i - \bar{X})^2}{n} \longrightarrow 0, n\rightarrow \infty.$$

I'd like to understand this response without asking in another e-mail. Why do we have this property based on the randomness of the $X$?

Comment: I suspect that if the fourth moment of $X$ is $k$ then you may find $E\left[\frac{\max_i (X_i - \bar{X})^2}{n}\right] \le \sqrt{\frac{k}{n}} \to 0$ as $n$ increases, or something like that

Comment: @Henry can you tell me what's the intuiton of your inequality? and why fourth moment and not the third?

Comment: I considered a non-negative discrete random variable $Y$ taking $n$ possible values $y_1,y_2,\ldots y_n$ each with probability $\frac1n$ (some of the values might be identical) where $E[Y^2]=k$.  I suspect this leads to $\max_i y_i^2 \le nk$, so  $\max_i y_i \le \sqrt{nk}$,  and $\frac{\max_i y_i}{n} \le \sqrt{\frac{k}{n}}$.  Now let $Y=(X-E[X])^2$ or something like that - we may have some flexibility since I think $\sqrt{k}$ may be larger than $E\left[(X_i - \bar{X})^2\right]$ , but it uses a fourth moment as related to the square of a central second moment. This is not a proof.